# The instance of entity type 'X' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id}' is already being tracked (nested object)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building an app to train myself with the ins and outs of C#/.NET
Here is the object structure involved :

```
public class StoreChain
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; } = null!;
        public int CreationYear { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StoreLocation> StoreLocations { get; set; } = new List<StoreLocation>();
    }
```

```
public class StoreLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public Address Address { get; set; } = null!;
        public StoreChain StoreChain { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

```
public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string? Coordinates { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Territory  { get; set; } = null!;
        public Country Country { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

```
public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string CountryAbbreviation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Here is the EF part :

```
public StoreChain? UpdateLocations(int Id, ICollection<StoreLocation> StoreLocations)
        {
            var storeChain = GetStoreChainById(Id);

            if (storeChain == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            storeChain.StoreLocations = StoreLocations;

            _context.StoreChain.Update(storeChain);
            var success = _context.SaveChanges() > 0;

            return success ? storeChain : null;
        }

public StoreChain? GetStoreChainById(int Id)
        {
            var storeChain = _context.StoreChain.Where(sc => sc.Id == Id)
                                  .FirstOrDefault();

            return storeChain;
        }
```

The error is thrown at the Country level.
If I try to add multiple locations in the same country for a given StoreChain object the exception is thrown when I attempt to persist the changes.

I did some reading on how EF works internally and I understand that it can't manage two instances of the same object in a given context, though I haven't found any clear answer as to how to handle a similar scenario.

Comment: Please show some code where you work with EF. Models are not enough.

Comment: Are you accidentally providing a non-zero value for the country's 'Id'? I agree, we need to see the code that adds the model to the context and calls SaveChanges

Comment: Where does `StoreLocations` come from?

Comment: What does `GetStoreChainById` do? Did it load the object using EF Core perhaps? You don't need to tell EF Core that an object has been updated, it will detect the changes itself. `Update` is only needed to tell EF Core to start tracking objects that didn't come from it

Comment: `I understand that it can't manage two instances of the same object in a given context,` that's wrong. There *shouldn't* be two instances in the first place. ORMs like EF Core or NHibernate try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. They detect changes in the objects they track automatically and persist all changes at once. The identity of an object is its primary key, so the same PK *does* mean the same in-memory object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So when different objects have the same instance of an object-property (a country in this case), how is it handled by the framework?

Comment: EF will only create a single Country object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Makes sense. I guess the question would be this.. in the scenario that we want to add multiple locations from the same Country, from a list as previously shown, what would be the smart way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to call `Update`. The `storeChain` object was loaded by EF and is being tracked by it. EF itself will detect any changes when the time comes to persist all changes to all loaded objects with `SaveChanges`.

By calling `Update` or `Add` you aren't saving anything to the database. You're telling EF to start tracking a "new" object in the `Modified` state or `Added` state. When EF checks its internal tracking tables, it sees that it *already* tracks an object with that identity and complains.

ORMs like EF Core or NHibernate try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. They detect changes in the objects they track automatically and persist all changes at once. The identity of an object is its primary key, so the same PK does mean the same in-memory object.

This way, a DbContext implements the Unit-of-Work pattern. If you call `SaveChanges`, everything gets persisted. If you dispose the context, the changes are discarded. There's no need for an explicit database connection or transaction. In fact, a DbContext instance will only open a connection when it needs to load objects or when it needs to persist changes.